# How to create a user profile with different views in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I've two type of users: Students and Institutions. 
Both can login in the website and they have different profiles views.

I'd like to use "http://example.com/accounts/" for both types of users but running different logics and displaying different templates for each one.

For example, Students when they go to their profile they can view/modify their attributes as what are they studying, interested courses.. etc. On the other side, the institution users can view/modify attributes of their own model as institution information.

Institution User Type:

```
class InstitutionProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='client')
gender = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=GENDERS_TYPES, blank=True)

#Contact Information
location = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
address = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=56, blank=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=56, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % format(self.user)
```

Student User Type:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
about_me = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=GENDERS_TYPES, blank=True)
birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
#Contact Information
location = models.ManyToManyField(Location, related_name='homecountry')
address = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=56, blank=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=56, blank=True)

#Interested
countries_interested = models.ManyToManyField(Location, blank=True, related_name='countries interested')
areas_interested = models.ManyToManyField(StudyArea, blank=True)
levels_interested = models.ManyToManyField(StudyLevel, blank=True)
languages_interested= models.ManyToManyField(LanguageCourse, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % format(self.user)
```

view.py

```
class InstitutionProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = get_user_model()
    slug_field = "username"
    template_name = "account/institution_profile.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        user = super(InstitutionProfileDetailView, self).get_object(queryset)
        InstitutionProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return user

class StudentProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = get_user_model()
    slug_field = "username"
    template_name = "account/student_profile.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        user = super(StudentProfileDetailView, self).get_object(queryset)
        StudentProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return user
```

What is the best solution for having different views with 2 different type of users?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: Two things, First of all, I'm using only one url for both views. www.example.com/account. Secondly, I'd like once the user is logged automatically display his own profile view. I mean, if the institution-user get logged automatically goes to the institution profile view and the same case for the student-user with his own view

Answer (score 1):

You can use an unified view and return different views from that according to your logic -

```
def accounts_view(request):
    if request.user.is_student(): # <-- check with your logic, is_student() is a stub
        return StudentProfileDetailView.as_view()
    elif request.user.is_institute():
        return InstitutionProfileDetailView.as_view()
```

And point `accounts/` to `accounts_view`.